# Why Angular 2+ innerHTML is calling method multiple times in a single statement, How to solve this

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, innerhtml

I have the template view like this.

```
<p [innerHTML]="myfunction()"></p>
```

and, ts file be like

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  myfunction(){
    alert(name);
    return '<div>abcd</div>';

  }
}
```

Its a simple method calling from html to render the html content through innerhtml, here the myfunction() is calling multiple times, and i'm getting multiple alerts, can anyone help me to solve this.

the stackblitz for this is [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f1ju4c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

thanks in advance

Comment: It's normal behavior: during the display cycle Angular will "recheck" the state of everything in case it changed since last step. Better to not call functions and instead put the value in a property. If the computation can be complex, call it within `ngOnInit` and store the result in a property, and display said property in the template. Not posting this as an answer since I'm not sure whether you're asking "why" this happens or if there's a workaround.

Comment: It is called multiple times because it called on every application tick, it's impossible for angular to detect if your method is idempotent.

Comment: I got to know, angular will recheck the state multiple time, in my project, i'm rending input element through innerHtml, when i type something in the input box, again its calling the same method , i need to get the value entered in the input element, this html i'm getting from server call , so i can't hardcode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pure pipe to only rerun it if inputs to the pipe have changed:

```
@Pipe({name: 'functionCaller'})
export class FunctionCallerPipe {
    transform(func: any, ...args: any[]): any {
        return func(...args);
    }
}
```

And use it like that:

```
<p [innerHTML]="myfunction| functionCaller : name"></p>
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  myfunction(name: string){
    alert(name);
    return '<div>' + name + '</div>';
  }
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks pokrishka, i will check this and comeback